# How to connect a countdowntimer to a button

Tags: android, button, countdown

I'm working with Android Studio. I'm creating an app that has a countdowntimer and a button. When I run the application, the timer automatically runs and if I want to click the button there is a TextView that counts how many times I press the button. I want the that timer starts when I press the button ,the countdown continue running and it stops at time "0:000" so it stops even the counting of clicks. Can you help me?
(if it helps I put the code)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    btnCount = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView textViewTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            count++;
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }

    });
    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textViewTimer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000
                    + ":" + millisUntilFinished % 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            textViewTimer.setText("0:000");
        }
    }.start();


}
```

I don't write the rest of the code of other things for privacy, but this is the interested part ;)

Comment: "if it helps I put the code"...it always helps. Please put the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

You can just save link to your CountDownTimer and use it anywhere you want. And for your issue you can have two boolean variables : `timerStarts` - responsible for start timer once, `timerProcessing` - responsible for check if timer is still processing.

Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
btnCount = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

boolean timerProcessing = false;
boolean timerStarts = false;

final TextView textViewTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
//Saving link to timer object
final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textViewTimer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000
            + ":" + millisUntilFinished % 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        textViewTimer.setText("0:000");
        timerProcessing = false;
    }
});

btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //start timer once when button first click
        if (!timerStarts){
            timer.start();
            timerStarts = true;
            timerProcessing = true;
        }

        if (timerProcessing){
            count++;
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }
}
});
}
```

Or you can have one variable (e.g. timerStarts), check it in button listener and set false when timer stops, but then when you click the button after timer stopped it will start again.
Hope it helps.

Comment: no, you haven't understood. I mean that when i run the app I want that it's all in pause, and then when i press the button the countdown starts so the count of the click starts. Then when the timer arrives to 0:000 i want that the count of the click finishes counting.

Comment: I`n glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the `Button` to stop counting clicks when the `CoundTownTimer` finishes. For this you can disable the `Button` when your timer finishes.

```
 public void onFinish() {
    textViewTimer.setText("0:000");
    btnCount.setEnabled(false);   // Add this line here
 }
```

If for some reason that doesn't work for you then you can use a `boolean` variable to decide whether or not to add to your count.

```
boolean addToCount = true;  // Create a variable

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    btnCount = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView textViewTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            count = (addToCount) ? count++ : count;  // Add 1 to count if 
                                                     // addToCount is true
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }

    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textViewTimer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000
                + ":" + millisUntilFinished % 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        textViewTimer.setText("0:000");
        addToCount = false;     // Change variable so count doesn't increase
    }
   }.start();
```